# How to know what chars are "word constituents" in latex-mode-syntax-table

Tags: syntax-table

In some of my query-replecements I need to have only alphabetic characters as word constituents in a local defined `syntax-table`. My approach is this:

```el
(with-syntax-table
   (let ((my-syntax-table (make-syntax-table latex-mode-syntax-table)))
     (modify-syntax-entry '(48 . 57) "_" my-syntax-table)
 ;; "_" = symbol constituent
 ;; '(48 . 57) = 0, 1, 2 ... 9
     
     (set-syntax-table my-syntax-table)
     (perform-replace "\\w+" "word" t t nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max))
     
     ))
```

How can find which other characters are `word-constituents` in `latex-mode-syntax-table`?

**EDIT.** I wrote this loop:

```el
(setq CHAR 0)
(while (<= CHAR 255)
(when (string-match-p "119" (prin1-to-string (char-syntax CHAR)))
  (insert (char-to-string CHAR) "\s"))
(setq CHAR (1+ CHAR))
```

That returns (after setting `latex-mode`):

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z                                 ¥ · À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý Þ ß à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ð ñ ò ó ô õ ö ø ù ú û ü ý þ ÿ

So I was wondering if there is another way to set only the alphabetic characters instead of `unset` the other ones.

Comment: E.g., `(aref latex-mode-syntax-table ?a)` gives `(2)` for the letter `a` which means `word` constituent. See [the doc about syntax table internals](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-Table-Internals.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the loop of the edited version of my question solved my problem. I want to share here the solution temporarily adopted. I'd like to know if there is something better (e.g. a more `compact` or elegant solution):

```
(defvar my-syntax-table
  (let ((table (make-syntax-table latex-mode-syntax-table)))
    (modify-syntax-entry '0 "_" table)           ; "_" = symbol constituent
    (modify-syntax-entry '39 "_" table)          ; '
    (modify-syntax-entry '(48 . 57) "_" table)   ; 0--9
    (modify-syntax-entry '(128 . 255) "_" table) 
    table))

(with-syntax-table my-syntax-table
  (perform-replace "\\w+" "word" t t nil 1 nil (point-min) (point-max))
  )
```

**EDIT.** I finally adopted the following solution to find which chars are class-c in a syntax-table:

```
(defun returnClassChars (CLASS SYNTAX_TABLE)
  "Classes:
-   whitespace character        /   character quote character
w   word constituent            $   paired delimiter
_   symbol constituent          '   expression prefix
.   punctuation character       <   comment starter
(   open delimiter character    >   comment ender
)   close delimiter character   !   generic comment delimiter
\"  string quote character      |   generic string delimiter
\\   escape character            @   inherit from \"standard-syntax-table\"'
"
  (with-output-to-temp-buffer "*Chars*"
    (princ (with-temp-buffer
         (with-syntax-table SYNTAX_TABLE
           (setq CHAR 0)
           (while (<= CHAR 255)
         (when (= (string-to-char CLASS)  (char-syntax CHAR))
           (insert (prin1-to-string CHAR) "\t" (char-to-string CHAR) "\n") )
         (setq CHAR (1+ CHAR))))
         (buffer-string)))))
```

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no reason to `set-syntax-table` when using `with-syntax-table`.  `(with-syntax-table my-syntax-table ...)`  The whole idea when using `with-syntax-table` is to have a *temporary* syntax table for the duration of the function call.  There may be benefit that I am not aware of to using `(make-char-table 'syntax-table nil)`, but I am accustomed to seeing `make-syntax-table` instead.

Comment: @lawlist You're right. I'll correct my post.